# Receiving Simple Data Through Intent for Android App while App is in background

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that receives simple data (text) from other apps through the other app sharing to my app. Part of the manifest looks like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".presentation.ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When the activity hasn't been created yet, I share the text data from the other app to my app and handle the intent with action intent.action.Send in the onCreate method. However, I also want to be able to share the text data while the app is in the background. When the app is in the background and I share the text data from the other app, the action is intent.action.MAIN in the onRestart or onResume methods.

This is the handleIntent method

```
private void handleIntent(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            // logic
        }
    }
}
```

How do I receive the text data from the other app while my app is in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

I overrode the newIntent method

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sending Simple Data to Other Apps

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps

**Update Your Manifest**

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Handle the Incoming Content**

```
 void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        }
    }
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}
```

Comment: The onCreate method isn't called when the activity is brought back into the foreground. And the intent that is sent is intent.action.Main.

Comment: you need to refresh activity