# How to reference Current Activity in ReactActivityLifecycleListener within a Expo Package?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-module

I am currently developing an Expo module that utilizes Intents to receive content from other applications. My issue currently is that, while the app is open in the background, a share intent is unsuccessful.

The issues is also outlined in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472474/receiving-simple-data-through-intent-for-android-app-while-app-is-in-background).

To resolve this, I need to hook into the Android lifecycle as described [here](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/android-lifecycle-listeners/). And here I am bit confused on how to access the current activity to set the intent?

What I basically want to achieve is this:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  Activity mActivity = getCurrentActivity();
  if(mActivity == null) { return; }
  mActivity.setIntent(intent);
}
```

But how can I accomplish this within Expo Package, as opposed to a Module? How can I get the Current Activity in this snippet?

```
android/src/main/java/expo/modules/mylib/MyLibReactActivityLifecycleListener.kt
package expo.modules.mylib

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import expo.modules.core.interfaces.ReactActivityLifecycleListener

class MyLibReactActivityLifecycleListener : ReactActivityLifecycleListener {
  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent): Boolean {
    // Your setup code in `Activity.onCreate`.
    doSomeSetupInActivityOnCreate(activity)
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any ideas.